# choice: flask, django api render to user search

Tags: python, django

I'm totally new to Django and working on a project to query data from a MongoDB usually my project is meant for the data, but in order to give it a sense and let the user see how is it, I'm required to create an API to fetch data based on queries sent by the user. My questions are:

is there any preexisted views in rest_framework that can satisfy my needs(All I want is let the user search the data, based on fields that he can enter)

Or should I use react as a frontend to send queries?

Another Q, would it be easy, how is this task on flask can it be done so quickly?

Please, if something is not clear, just ask?

Comment: I think django rest framework is sufficient enough for your usecase. Here are generic views provided by drf https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/ ListAPIView or RetrieveAPIView can be used in your case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like swagger ui and redoc, or graphql.

Just an off-track suggestion, you can try fastapi. https://fastapi.tiangolo.com

The reason why it is recommended is because it makes a lot of effort on interactive API documentation, which is basically used out of the box. It is fast and easy to learn.

A small example, although it is incomplete and does not fit your purpose: https://github.com/psiace/fastdash